# Dismiss view, then show another one?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewanimationtransition

I have a iPhone app where I want to hide the first view, then show the second view smoothly. Here's my code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

SettingsViewController *screentwothree = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"settingsView" bundle:nil];
screentwothree.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:screentwothree animated:NO];
[screentwothree release];
}
```

However, it crashes with no errors.

Please help!
Coulton

PS: Would it be easier to use a UINavigationView? If so, can you please post some example code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use performSelector with delay to show the second view half a second after dissmising the first one. 
It would also allow you have animations, making a smoother transition.